# Column being ignored in like statement of SQL where clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a jQuery autocomplete search box with a C# Web Service querying for results in a SQL Server table of contacts.

The table has columns for `ContactID, ContactType, FirstName, LastName`, and `Organization` and I'm currently trying to allow the user to search by either `FirstName` and `Lastname` when `ContactType` is set to `IND` (for individual) or `Organization` when it's not.

The problem I'm having is that for a particular contact who has their `ContactType` set to `ORG` (for organization) I'm still only able to return their result by typing the contact's first and last name. It displays the result's name as the organization name but if I search by the actual organization name it doesn't return any results. My query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN contacttype= 'IND' AND FirstName != '' AND LastName != ''
                 OR ContactType IS NULL THEN FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' ' + Email1 
            ELSE Organization + ' ' + Email1
        END AS FullName, 
       ContactID
  FROM Contact 
 WHERE Updated = '1' 
   AND Organization LIKE @SearchText 
    OR FirstName + ' ' + LastName LIKE @SearchText + '%' 
 ORDER BY FullName ASC
```

Comment: try using some line breaks for readability and `(` parenthesis `)` to make sure your `AND`s and `OR`s are as expected

Comment: You are adding `%` to your `@searchText` when searching by name, but nothing was added when searching by Organization.

Comment: I think you'll need to use parenthesis like this `and (Organization like @SearchText or FirstName + ' ' + LastName like @SearchText + '%')`

Comment: You need to use parenthesis in your case expression AND your where predicates.

Comment: Do you care if the query is totally unperformant?

Comment: @Remus or inefficient?

Comment: Thanks it was the missing % that was causing it.

Comment: Did the missing % answer your question? If so, @NickyvV should put the comment as an answer so you can mark it accepted.

Comment: Yes that was it, please do submit that as an answer @NickyvV so that I can mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @pixelmeow, I thought that was my comment?? @NickyvV didn't say anything about the `%`, but anyway, OP should just accept @Paddy's answer...

Comment: Whoops, you're right, @Bolu. I'm sorry. :(

Comment: Sorry about that @Bolu I misread it as well (kind of a hectic day at the office). If you'd like to submit your comment as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `%` to your `@searchText` when searching by name, but nothing was added when searching by Organization. And you may need to use parenthesis depending on your logic (note: I added one below based on my guess).

```
SELECT CASE WHEN contacttype= 'IND' AND FirstName != '' AND LastName != ''
                 OR ContactType IS NULL THEN FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' ' + Email1 
            ELSE Organization + ' ' + Email1
        END AS FullName, 
       ContactID
 FROM Contact 
 WHERE Updated = '1' 
   AND (Organization LIKE @SearchText + '%' 
        OR FirstName + ' ' + LastName LIKE @SearchText + '%') 
 ORDER BY FullName ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

You have some issues with your `AND`s and your `OR`s, I think you may need something like:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN (contacttype= 'IND' AND FirstName != '' AND LastName != '') 
                 OR ContactType is null 
                 THEN FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' ' + Email1 
            ELSE Organization + ' ' + Email1 
        END AS FullName, 
       ContactID 
  FROM Contact 
 WHERE Updated = '1' 
   AND (Organization LIKE @SearchText 
       OR FirstName + ' ' + LastName LIKE @SearchText + '%') 
 ORDER BY FullName ASC
```

---

Also as noted by bolu in the comments, you don't append a wildcard for your org name search.  This may be required, depending on what you are passing in.

Comment: Thanks but it's still acting the same way when I altered my query to this. The data I'm using isn't structured very well at all (I was redesinging an application and using the existing data) and I think the reason why this is happening is because the organization also has a first name and last name. The way the data should have been structured was if it was an organization, only set the organization value and vice versa for individuals but as it stands, that's how it's structured.

Comment: @TonyBarsotti  Did you add the wildcard search to the org name as well?